# convert/wrap a "classic" asynchronous method that uses a callback

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback, async-await, windows-phone-8

I´m trying to convert a  "classic" asynchronous method that uses a callback into a async/await method.

This is the code:

```
authClient.LoginCompleted += authClient_LoginCompleted;
authClient.LoginAsync(new List<string>() { "var1", "var2" }, data);

static void authClient_LoginCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
{ ... }
```

Where "`data`" is a `UserState`, and  `authClient_LoginCompleted` is the callback.

I already have the logic for a async/await methods, the problem is that the interaction in windows phone with Microsoft.Live uses callbacks. I´m considering a solution using semaphore, in order not to change the logic I have. That could be a good option?

Answer (score 11):

If you need to wrap asynchronous callbacks into `Task`s, then you can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. [MSDN has the full details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx).

However, in your case, you can just use `LoginAsync` without the `UserState` parameter:

```
LiveLoginResult result = await authClient.LoginAsync(new[] { "var1", "var2" });
```

Comment: This link is very useful for understanding the useges of the TaskCompletionSource: http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2013/01/27/using-asyncawait-with-webclient-in-windows-phone-8-or-taskcompletionsource.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+galasoft+%28Laurent+Bugnion+%28GalaSoft%29%29&utm_content=Google+Reader